# Matrix multiplication running times Python < C++ < Matlab - Explain

Tags: c++, python, matlab, opencv, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix `M` thats's `16384 x 81`. I want to compute `M * M.t` (the result will be `16384x16384`).

My question is: **could somebody please explain the running time differences**?

Using **OpenCV in C++** the following code takes **18 seconds**

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace cv;
int main(void) {
  Mat m(16384, 81, CV_32FC1);
  randu(m, Scalar(0), Scalar(1));
  int64 tic = getTickCount();
  Mat m2 = m * m.t();
  printf("%f", (getTickCount() - tic) / getTickFrequency());
}
```

In **Python** the following code takes <s>only **0.9 seconds**</s> **18.8 seconds** (see comment below)

```
import numpy as np
from time import time
m = np.random.rand(16384, 81)
tic = time()
result = np.dot(m, m.T)
print (time() - tic)
```

In **MATLAB** the following code takes **17.7 seconds**

```
m = rand(16384, 81); 
tic;
result = m * m';
toc;
```

---

My only guess would have been that it's a memory issue, and that somehow Python is able to avoid swap space. When I watch `top`, however, I do not see my `C++ application` using all the memory, and I had expected that `C++` would win the day. Thanks for any insights.

**Edit**

After revising my examples to time only the operation, the code now takes 18 seconds with Python, also. I'm really not sure what's going on, but if there's enough memory, they all seem to perform the same now.

Here are timings if the number of rows is 8192:
C++: 4.5 seconds
Python: 4.2 seconds
Matlab: 1.8 seconds

Comment: the computational intensive routines in numpy are written in C, so it's not surprising that numpy is this fast -- but not sure why it is much faster than OpenCV.

Comment: Does Numpy perform lazy evaluation?  In other words, perhaps it's the case that it hasn't actually calculated anything at this stage; instead, merely storing the fact that it needs to perform the calculation if anyone ever accesses `result`?

Comment: @Geoff, why do you measure the time of `rand()`? If you want to measure GEMM (multiply time), you should not measure a rand time. Also, there can be a startup time of the programm.

Comment: So much for Python being slow! ;)

Comment: I added timing code around the operation itself to each of the examples. It turns out that simply doing this bumped Python's time up to 18 seconds. Do you think I should close this? I don't want to confuse future readers.

Comment: @Jesse Cohen: It does not depend on `C`. `numpy` just is capable to use  proper libraries. However so is `matlab` as well, so they should be close to each other. There is no `Python` magic here. Thanks

Comment: @Oli: There is no lazy evaluation involved. Does someone have `matlab` (with enough memory) to verify timings? Thanks

Comment: You know, just on first glance, it would seem the answer is "there's a horrid bug in OpenCV, did you tell them?"

Comment: @Geoff: How you do your timing is not correct, or is't just typos here?

Comment: @eat - I'm pretty sure I copied and pasted my code above. Is there some problem with one of the examples?

Comment: I'm sorry this question is getting so confusing. It seems that everything is running with the same running times now. I must be hitting a memory limit that occasionally forces C++ to swap out memory. I have added timings for fewer rows to the question.

Comment: You know, just on first glance, it would seem the answer is "there's a horrid bug in OpenCV, did you tell them?"  Other than that, I'd be tempted to make sure I was using the SAME matrix in each example; there's always the chance that the array you generate randomly in the OpenCV example is somehow horridly ill-conditioned, or contrariwise in the others.

Comment: @Charlie, good point. It's also possible there are more zeros in some cases than others. I am running each example a number of times to confirm (and push memory out) though.

Comment: Consider also using `import timeit` and `numpy.inner(m, m)`.

Comment: @Geoff: Well many things, but few; in `matlab` it's commonly `tic` `toc` pairs. Also don't count on one single run, average over several runs. Don't do timings with array sizes close to your max memory. Perhaps a better indicator is throughput (bytes/ s). Even modest machines higher than 5 GB/s should be expected with dot products. If significantly less, you are dotting very very small ones or there is hard disk involved (too much).

Comment: timings on my machine: c++ 9.0, python 2.8, octave 2.1 seconds for `8192` case https://gist.github.com/7c1921a7bca7094136f7/d9045273d1784028a397bf62f89d3a399fa96a52

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What CPU are you running on?  For modern x86 and x64 chips with dynamic clocking, `getTickCount` and `getTickFrequency` cannot be trusted.

18 seconds is long enough to get acceptable precision from the standard OS functions based on the timer interrupt.

And what BLAS are you using with OpenCV?  MatLab installs some highly optimized ones, IIRC even detecting your CPU and loading either Intel's or AMD's math library appropriately.